# Compiler fails if having both `@Insert` and `@Upsert` in Room DAO (Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-room, android-jetpack

I have the following code:

```
package com.example.secondcompose.dao

import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Delete
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.OnConflictStrategy
import androidx.room.Query
import androidx.room.Upsert
import com.example.secondcompose.data.Phone
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow

@Dao
interface PhoneDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.NONE)
    suspend fun insertIfMissing(phone: Phone)

    @Upsert
    suspend fun upsert(phone: Phone)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(phone: Phone)

    @Query("DELETE FROM phone")
    suspend fun nuke()

    @Query("SELECT * FROM phone WHERE id = :id")
    fun find(id: Long): Flow<Phone?>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM phone ORDER BY manufacturer ASC")
    fun getPhonesOrderedByManufacturer(): Flow<List<Phone>>
}
```

However it fails to compile:

```
C:\Users\szmar\AndroidStudioProjects\SecondCompose\app\build\generated\ksp\debug\java\com\example\secondcompose\dao\PhoneDao_Impl.java:160: error: cannot find symbol
          __insertionAdapterOfPhone.upsert(phone);
                                   ^
  symbol:   method upsert(Phone)
  location: variable __insertionAdapterOfPhone of type EntityInsertionAdapter<Phone>
```

If I comment out the `@Insert` and `insertIfMissing` it compiles. Why? What's the proper solution here?

Comment: Looks like using `IGNORE` instead of `NONE` helped for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/Upsert#onConflict()) for `onConflict`, the value `NONE` is equivalent to not using the statement at all.  I recommend using one of the following instead:

> Use OnConflictStrategy.ABORT (default) to roll back the transaction on conflict. Use OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE to replace the existing rows with the new rows. Use OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE to keep the existing rows.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/OnConflictStrategy#NONE()